# How to add UIRefreshControl on UITableView bottom?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

I want to implement pull to refresh effect but on `UITableView` bottom using `UIRefreshControl` ?

Any ideas?

Comment: You can do anything you like with the table view's [background view](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/backgroundView), including putting a refresh control at the bottom of it; but you won't get magical automatic operation of the refresh control

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to put `UIRefreshControll` to bottom of `UITableView` in a manner similar to putting it to top. But anyway, you're able to place everything on table view's background view.

But the solution which I prefer is to download additional items when user scrolls to the most bottom of table view. I handle it via `UITableViewControllerDelegate` method:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == self.items.count - 1 {
        // Download more items
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

These are the two things i typically do:

1. Configure a Footer View which displays the loading Indicator.
2. Provide a additional cell from the TableViews or CollectionViews
   Datasource which presents a loading indicator. Depending on the current loading state it could display a label like "No more items available" or the actual Indicator